# Question in regards to finding the angle of a triangle given an non-common trig ratio, without a calculator.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

While doing some basic trig review, I came across a question that asked us to find $\cos(\theta)$ and $\tan(\theta)$ in the domain of $\pi < \theta < \frac {3 \pi}{ 2}$ given that $\sin(\theta) = -\frac 14$.

I got the following ratios:
$\cos(\theta) = {\dfrac{\sqrt{15}}{4}}$ and $\tan(\theta) = \frac {-1} {\sqrt{15}}$. This is where the question officially ends, but I was wondering how one would find the actual value of the $\theta$, without using an inverse trig function on one's calculator. I understand how to do this for any angles in intervals of $\frac {\pi}{12}$ (since they are special angles) but how does one do it for non-special angles?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general the answer is no. Is a  question frequently asked by my students (high school 16 y.o.). The answer is Calculus.

A mathematician named [Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brook_Taylor)  in the beginning of 18th century invented a way to approximate functions like sine cosine etc via polynomials whose name is (guess how?) Taylor's polynomials.

For instance inverse sin can be written, for values close to $0$, as

$\arcsin x=x+\dfrac{x^3}{6}+\dfrac{3 x^5}{40}+ R(x)$

I can't explain now the way to compute the polynomial, but the higher the degree the more precise the result and the remainder $R(x)$ becomes smaller. BTW this is more or less the way the calculator and the computer calculates functions like this.

Thus you plug $x=0.25$ in the previous formula and get (18th century mathematician did this by hand. They had tables with thousands of values for sin cos tan and log all calculated by hand up to SEVEN decimal digits! A lot of work opportunities for mathematicians at that time :))

$\arcsin 0.25 \approx 0.252677$

this result is in radians. In degrees is about $ \arcsin 0.25 \approx 14°\, 21'$

between $\pi$ and $\dfrac{3\pi}{2}$ we have that $\arcsin -\dfrac{1}{4}\approx \pi+\arcsin \dfrac{1}{4}\approx 3.39427 \approx 194° \,29'$

BTW your cosine is wrong because in the interval we are talking about cosine is negative. The actual value is negative

Hope this helps